# Calculate pandas dataframe index difference based on the value of another column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the difference in index of the current row with the row WHERE a certain column has a certain value.

i.e.

I have a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

# pandas settings
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 320)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1320)
pd.set_option('display.width', 320)

df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy94jp4d7qwmv04/eurusd_df1.csv?dl=1')
```

So I would like to calculate how many indexes behind is the row with *candle = candle-20*

So for instance, if current row is 583185 and the candle value is 119, then the candle we are interested in is 99. We need to figure out *current_index - index(where candle=99 1st occurrence)*

I hope I made myself clear, cheers =)

**EDIT:** 
Ok, I did pretty bad explaination above..

I believe I'm actually quite close to solving this myself. Have a look:

```
x = df.index[df.candle == df.candle - 20][0]
df['test'] = df.bid.rolling(int(x)).mean()
```

So the 'test' column should be the mean() value of the df.bid last X rows, where X is how many rows between current df.candle and the one that is 20 candles back (first iteration so [0] (there are many rows with same candle value))

But the code above gives an error:

*IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0*

Comment: can you add a data sample and an expected output? Thanks

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/hy94jp4d7qwmv04/eurusd_df1.csv?dl=1')

Comment: I have a formula: ```b = 0.015 * TP.rolling(X).std()``` I need to calculate rolling.(X) - depending on a value of another column. So X should be the index difference between current row and row where value of candle is -20 from current (first iteration)

Comment: What is TP? Also, that CSV is more than 78 MB in size, which is very large for slow internet connections. If you can trim it down to a subset of the data required to demonstrate your problem, that would be helpful.

Comment: I've added an EDIT

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to accomplish this:

```
# Generate example data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.Series(np.round(np.random.rand(1000000)*1000), dtype=int, name='candle').to_frame()

# Compute row index where df.candle is 20 less than candle_value at current_index
current_index = 583185
candle_value = df.loc[current_index, 'candle'] # = 119 in your df
index = df.index[df.candle == candle_value - 20][0]
print(index)
```

```
835
```

**Edit:** To compute the difference in indexes, just subtract them:

```
X = current_index - index
print(X)
```

```
582350
```

Then you can compute your formula:

```
b = 0.015 * TP.rolling(X).std()
```

Comment: You got it a bit wrong actually. I have a formula: ```
b = 0.015 * TP.rolling(X).std()``` I need to calculate rolling.(X) - depending on a value of another column. So X should be the index difference between current row and row where value of candle is -20 from current (first iteration)